# Hiding the menu by clicking on the area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a button and a drop-down menu, tell me please What should I do so after the click on a menu area it wont hide, and after the click out of the menu area it will hide? Now it opens by clicking, and closes by clicking on the button and on the menu area.

```js
$(function(){

$('.click').click(function() {
    $('.click-menu').slideToggle(200);
  });

  });
```

```css
.click {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.click span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.click-menu {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 110px;
 left: 50px;

}

.click-menu div {
 width:300px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: green;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="click">
   <span>CLICK</span>
   <div class="click-menu">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="main.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why click-menu div is child of click div?

Comment: @sam it has a complex structure. Here is a block as an example. Is that a problem?

Comment: I think this can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it

Comment: The problem that I see is, click event applies entire click div which includes clicking on child elements as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not the best way to do it but it works :

```js
$(function(){

  $('.click').click(function() {
    $('.click-menu').slideToggle(200);
  });
  
  $('html').click( function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).closest('.click').length===0 && $(e.target).closest(".click-menu").length===0) {
      $('.click-menu').slideUp(200);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.click {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.click span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.click-menu {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 110px;
 left: 50px;

}

.click-menu div {
 width:300px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: green;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="click">
 <span>CLICK</span>
    </div>
    <div class="click-menu">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
    </div>
   
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="main.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vladimir Prydatko, [17.12.19 22:06]
The code works fine if the block with the button and menu are two separate elements. But my block with the menu is situated inside the block with the button. And if I click on the menu then it is hiding.
How can I fix it? Just put them out separately?

Comment: In this case you just have to replace $('.click') with $('.click>span')

Comment: In this case, it appears and immediately hides

Comment: It's weird. I just tried it and it works. But only clicking on the span (the "CLICK" string), not the entire red button. I don't know why you really want to let your menu inside the button. It's not a good idea.

Comment: Namely on the button in any way?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last question. I do my best, but my English isn't very good.

Comment: Is it possible to make exactly a click on the button?

Comment: help me please)))

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the event on the span, not the parent. Style the span accordingly. Then detect on a click on the html whether there is a parent named "click". If not, close the menu.

```js
$(function(){

$('.click span').click(function() {
    $('.click-menu').slideToggle(200);
  });

$("html").click(function(e){
   if ( $(e.target).parents(".click").length ) {
  e.stopPropagation();
 } else {
  $('.click-menu').slideToggle(200);
 }
});

  });
```

```css
.click {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.click span {
 position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.click-menu {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 110px;
 left: 50px;

}

.click-menu div {
 width:300px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: green;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="click">
   <span>CLICK</span>
   <div class="click-menu">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="main.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```